# Moving character AI in multiplayer using PHP

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence, multiplayer

I have a Multiplayer browser game, and I want to add animals to it. I would like the animals to be able to walk randomly in the map.
I thought about putting the AI in the page with the animals, but I'm afraid that if there is more than one player in the room it'll mess up the AI since it'll be activated multiple times.

EDIT:

The player will be able to interact with the animals and kill them. Im trying to do a system that spawns a few animals when the player enters a room, and then he can approach it and fight it. if he doesnt fight the animal, it'll just stay there and move randomly untill there arent any players in the room.
Every room will have it's own animals, so if there are 2 players in the room they'll see the same animals. The animal's posiition will be saved in MySQL, and using AJAX I'm going to update the position of the animal. The only thing Javascript does is showing the animal to the player on the map.

What is the best way to do the AI? And is it possible in PHP? (Im not talknig about the random movement specificly, I also mean the AI code for other things that the animal will do.)
I googled it and couldn't find what I needed.

P.S: I built the game using PHP and JQuery. (and of course CSS and HTML)

Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: If you have the rest of it written including collision detection, multiplayer interactions, etc. it seems that randomly either standing still or moving in a random direction would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on so many aspects of your application but mainly these points:

- Technical architecture
- Role of the animals

If those animals are purely decorative, you might want to implement them in JavaScript in the client. The other extreme would be animals that can be hunted for food, then you would need to store the information of each animal on the server (a database like mysql or something in memory maybe) PLUS you need some process that lets each AI make its descicions at a certain interval. To avoid huge system load, it might be wise to "forget about" animals at a certain distance from all players and generate new ones when players approach.

Edit:
Since the animals aren't just for decoration, you should write an AI job (in PHP, if you like), that reads each room's state including its players and animals and steers the animals' movements based on the situation. The following article explains how to call your AI job script: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Comment: The animals arent just for "Beauty", I edited the question and added a bit more details.